# Please explain how regex non-zero lookbehind assertion works in clear language

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain in clear language how the non-zero lookbehind assertion `(?<=.)` technically works in the example below? That is, can you actually walk through it? The code works fine and produces the correct result.

I read about `(?<=\w)` at http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html, but the explanation was not clear to someone trying to learn about lookbehind assertions. Thanks.

```
>>> text = 'sassy'   
>>> for (regexp,subst) in [ (r'(?<=.)s', '5'),(r'^s', '$') ]:  
...   text = re.sub(regexp,subst,text)
...  
>>> text
'$a55y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look-behind does just that: it verifies that whatever precedes the current character matches the look-behind expression.

In your case, `(?<=.)s` will match `s`, but only if what precedes it matches `.` (i.e. anything except CRLF).

Comment: Thanks, Denis. Can you tell me the difference between the above and (?:.) which also seems to provide the right result? Does <= actually mean less than or equal to in this case?

Comment: `(?<=regex)` means look behind the current position and match regex (without catching it). `(regex)` defines a group, catching it. `(?:regex)` defines a group, without catching it. e.g. `a(b|c)` matches `ab` and catches `b`, while `a(?:b|c)` matches the same without catching `b` (thus eating less memory).

Comment: So in (?<=.)s, 's' is matched if there is a previous character. And likewise in (?:.)s ,'s' is matched if there is a previous character. And in both cases, the 's' is not caught? Is that what you are saying? Then what is the difference between them? @Denis

Comment: And in (?:.)s ,'s' is matched if there is a previous character. And in both cases, the 's' is not caught? Is that what you are saying? Then what is the difference between them? @Denis

Comment: In both cases, `s` is caught. The difference lies in that what the regex as a whole will consider a match. `((?<=.)s)` (note the extra bracket) would capture `s` in `test`, whereas `((?:.)s)` would capture `es`.

Comment: Or, put another way: `t(?:.)st` would match `test`, whereas `t(?<=.)st` would not (it would match `tst` instead).

Comment: First, there is this concept of a *match*. If a match happens, then there is the concept of match *groups*. An assertion is never a part of any group in a match. The entire text that is matched is always in the *default group* (``mo.group(0)``). Additionally, you can have *sub-groups* within the default group. If you use ``(?:)`` text matched by it is part of the over-all match, hence part of the default group, but it will *not* go in an own sub-group.

Comment: Thank you very much, Denis (and ThomasH). This is all new to me so sorry for my slow understanding about ?<= and ?:                    I suppose your explanation would explain why one of the s does not get converted. I would have thought the second s would also get converted because it is preceded by a character.      Can you explain this please?                                                           >>> text='sassy'
>>> for (regexp,subst) in [ (r'(?:.)s', '5'),(r'^s', '$') ]: 
...  text = re.sub(regexp,subst,text)
...  
>>> text
'$5sy'

Comment: Thank you very much, @Denis (and ThomasH). This is all new to me so sorry for my slow understanding about ?<= and ?:                    I suppose your explanation would explain why one of the s does not get converted. I would have thought the second s would also get converted because it is preceded by a character.      Can you explain this please?                                                           >>> text='sassy'
>>> for (regexp,subst) in [ (r'(?:.)s', '5'),(r'^s', '$') ]: 
...  text = re.sub(regexp,subst,text)
...  
>>> text
'$5sy'

Comment: I think you really need to look into a tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you, @ Denis, for all your help.